# How to import multiple macros?

Tags: php, symfony, macros, twig

**I want to elegantly import multiple macros from a single place.**

I created a file called "macros.twig" and have included it into my template:

```
{% include "_includes/macros" %}
```

Within that file, I hoped to import all my available macros like so:

```
{% import "_includes/macros/snippets" as snippets %}
{% import "_includes/macros/timestamp" as timestamp %}
{% import "_includes/macros/telephone" as telephone %}
{% import "_includes/macros/subscribe" as subscribe %}
{% import "_includes/macros/image" as image %}
{% import "_includes/macros/admin" as admin %}
```

This sort-of modular approach was suppose to make it easier to manage the macros I want to use globally; without cluttering the head of my main layout.

Currently, when I call a macro this way, I get a **"Variable "subscribe" does not exist"** error.

What's the preferred method of importing multiple macros at one time?

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't your include statement include the `macros.twig` file?

Comment: Yeah... I had this same problem... The solution I went through was a bit complex, ended up making a Twig Extension bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`macro` tag in Twig is a kind of function you can use to avoid code repetition and is meant for a single template with `{% import _self as macro %}` or to be shared between some different templates for a group of controllers using the same view variables.

If you need to use a function globally in twig you better create a `\Twig_SimpleFunction`.

see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

#### Edited based on comment

Anyway you could have something like this to autoload macro :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Twig/MacroAutoloadExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class MacroAutoloadExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            // "*"" is used to get "template_macro" as $macro as third argument
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('macro_*', array($this, 'getMacro'), array(
                'needs_environment' => true, // $env first argument will render the macro
                'needs_context' => true,     // $context second argument an array of view vars
                'is_safe' => array('html'),  // function returns escaped html
                'is_variadic' => true,       // and takes any number of arguments
            ))
        );
    }

    public function getMacro(\Twig_Environment $env, array $context, $macro, array $vars = array())
    {
        list($name, $func) = explode('_', $macro);

        $notInContext = 0; // helps generate unique context key

        $varToContextKey = function ($var) use (&$context, $name, $func, &$notInContext) {
            if (false !== $idx = array_search($var, $context, true)) {
                return $idx;
            }

            // else the var does not belong to context
            $key = '_'.$name.'_'.$func.'_'.++$notInContext;
            $context[$key] = $var;

            return $key;
        };

        $args = implode(', ', array_map($varToContextKey, $vars));

        $twig = <<<EOT
{% import '_includes/macros/$name.twig' as $name %}
{{ $name.$func($args) }}
EOT;

        try {
            $html = $env->createTemplate($twig)->render($context);
        } catch (\Twig_Error $e) {
            $e->setTemplateFile(sprintf('_includes/macro/%s.twig', $name));

            throw $e;
        }

        return $html;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'macro_autoload_extension';
    }
}
```

Register the extension :

```
# app/config/sevices.yml
services:
    ...
    app.macro_autoload_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\MacroAutoloadExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Write some macros :

```
{# app/Resources/views/_includes/macros/list.twig #}
{% macro ol(array) %}
    {% if array is iterable %}
        <ol>
        {% for item in array %}
            <li>
            {% if item is iterable %}
                {% for sub_item in item %}{{ macro_list_ul(sub_item) }}{% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {{ item }}
            {% endif %}
            </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    {% else %}
        <ol><li>{{ array }}</li></ol>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% macro ul(array) %}
    {% if array is iterable %}
        <ul>
        {% for key, item in array %}
            {{ key }}:
            {% if item is iterable %}
                {% for sub_item in item %}{{ macro_list_ul(sub_item) }}{% endfor %}
            {% else %}{{ item }}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <ul><li>{{ array }}</li></ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

#### Then you can use everywhere in you views :

`{{ macro_list_ol(['un', 'deux', 'trois']) }}`

or:

```
{% set hash = { 'one': 1, 'two': 'deux', 'posts': posts } %} 
{{ macro_list_ul(hash) }}
```

#### Bonus

Usually when you import macro in a template (one file) with `_self` or from another template, if you need a macro in a set tag, the macro is not available since `set` tag has a different scope than `_self` (even if it shares context) :

```
{# /app/Resources/views/includes/macro/outer.html.twig #}
{% macro function(args) %}
    ...
{% endmacro %}
```

plus

```
{# /app/Resources/views/Bundle/Controller/action.html.twig #}
{% macro inner_macro(arg1, arg2) %}
    {# render something #}
    {# cannot access context of this view, only args #}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as inner %}
{% import '/includes/macro/outer_macro.html.twig' as outer %} {# cannot access context either %}

...

{% set some_var %}
    {# can access context but neither outer or inner #}
    {{ inner.inner_macro('yes', 64) }} {# will not work #}
    {# you need to do import _self as inner again %}

    {# this is fix by both my answer and the one by @KalZekdor #}
    {{ macro_outer_function(var_from_context) }} {# will work #}
{% endset %}

{{ some_var }}
```

You can even call macro from macro without using import.

### Update

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/HeahDude/f9aeb128fcac309dddc8)

Comment: Using a function that manually interpolates and outputs html kind of defeats the purpose of using a templating engine like Twig in the first place.

I do the above for extending Twig functionality, such as adding some php functions (get_class, for example), defining tests or filters, but it's not the best way to access macros from any twig template. You'd want your snippets and etc to be written in your templating language (i.e., Twig), so you isolate the domains of responsibility. What happens when your designer who knows html and barely knows twig needs to modify a snippet?

Comment: @KalZekdor I have updated my answer, thanks for pointing this

Comment: Update: refactored the callable filtering arguments

Comment: When I first saw this answer, I had a very hard time understanding just about anything it was doing. I'm very much a PHP beginner and I've just spent the past 2 weeks figuring out exactly how this works... line by line. I was especially taken-back with the use of "<<<EOT". At long last, I've finally manage to successfully implement this into my project. Thank you very much for all your work on this. I can see myself using this regularly.

Comment: Glad that helped ;) You should check the gist as someone forked it today and made it very simple, this should help too :)

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit difficult for me, as well, but I put together a nice bundle with an Event Listener that autoloads the macros.

```
namespace App\Common\UIExtensionBundle\Listeners;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;

class UIExtenderListener
{
    private $macroNamespace = 'ui';

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $oTwig, $aMacros)
    {
        $this->twig = $oTwig;

        //Macros
        $this->macros = $aMacros;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $oEvent)
    {
        $templates = [];
        foreach ($this->macros as $macro => $template)
        {
            $templates[$macro] = $this->twig->loadTemplate($template);
        }

        $this->twig->addGlobal($this->macroNamespace, $templates);

    }
}
```

The services.xml for the bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="uiext.macros" type="collection">
            <parameter key="test">UIXBundle:ui:test.html.twig</parameter>
            <parameter key="list">UIXBundle:ui:list.html.twig</parameter>
            <parameter key="entity">UIXBundle:ui:entity.html.twig</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="uiext.extender" class="App\Common\UIExtensionBundle\Listeners\UIExtenderListener" scope="container">
            <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" priority="1000" />
            <argument type="service" id="twig"/>
            <argument>%uiext.macros%</argument>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Here's the `views\ui\list.html.twig` file:

```
{% macro ol(arr) %}
    <ol>
        {% for item in arr %}
            <li>{{ item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro ul(arr) %}
    <ul>
        {% for item in arr %}
            <li>{{ item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

Then, from any twig template, just add `{{ ui.list.ul(listArr) }}`

Comment: I think your answer is good, but you may want to avoid loading all the templates for each request. By making a customised twig extension you only load dynamically the template you need when you call it in twig templates which is almost the same as the "normal" process.

Comment: @Heah If you have thousands of Macros, yeah, that might be a concern, but Twig is fairly efficient as is. JIT loading of Macros seems like a case of premature optimization, adding a lot of complexity just to eke out a millisecond or two.

Comment: Thank you Kal, I too have spent the last couple of weeks studying your work. While I appreciate your concerns with some of the ways Heah has approached the problem, I do see value in not needing the XML file. However, your approach did still work. So thank you, it has proved very useful.

Comment: True, but if you have another way that you want to retrieve the list of Macros, you can implement that in the Listener's __construct, instead of passing them through as service configuration data. Either way, glad you got it working, but the information might be useful to anyone else trying something similar.