# Symfony2 twig share macros across bundles

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm developing symfony2 bundles for internal use in our company and I want to share some twig code (macros) across them, is there any way to do that?

I've tried to create normal library and import macros from there, but it doesn't work, I guess twig can't find the file, something with namespaces.\

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import multiple macros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136997/how-to-import-multiple-macros)

Answer (score 0):

Register a **namespaced Twig paths**

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/acme/foo-bar/templates": foo_bar
```

Use it

```
{{ include('@foo_bar/macros.twig') }}
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Comment: Yes, this will work, but I want my macros to be separate library, that way I'll be able to update my macros only. I want my macros to be something like module that I could add with composer.